# Order By String Property Value and Pagination in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, pagination

I am using neo4j to create a social network application. The data model has a `FRIEND` relationship between two `USER` nodes. I need to get all the friends of mine ordered by `displayName` (Unique Indexed).

I need pagination for this query. I will send the last name from the list I got from the previous query results. And I want to limit each page to 20 names.

```
MATCH (u:USER{displayName:{id}})-[:FRIEND]-(f:USER)
RETURN f
ORDER BY f.displayName
LIMIT 20;
```

What is the best way to do this? Will `SKIP` work here, sending `SKIP 0`, `SKIP 1*20`, `SKIP 2*20`, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query in this way i think :

```
ORDER BY f.displayName LIMIT START_POSITION , LAST_POSITION;
```

For example:

```
ORDER BY f.displayName LIMIT 0 , 20;
ORDER BY f.displayName LIMIT 21 , 40;
```

Comment: Do it as the following ORDER BY f.displayName LIMIT START_POSITION , START_POSITION+20 ;

Comment: It's not working there is no limit from and to range in neo4j.That one I used in SQL Db but in neo4j its not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `SKIP` clause to do what you want. In the following, I assume that you provide the `page` value (starting at 0) as a parameter.

```
MATCH (u:USER{displayName:{id}})-[:FRIEND]-(f:USER)
RETURN f
ORDER BY f.displayName
SKIP {page} * 20
LIMIT 20;
```

Note that this technique is not foolproof if the list of friends can change during paging.